# Transaction failing with Error : 403 Organization total events daily limit exceeded

Tags: platform-event

I have stopped all the process builders and commented code which were publishing the event.
When i query 'PlatformEventUsageMetrics' for 24 hours, platform_event_delivered has already reached beyond 50k while platform_event_published is still 0.

How is this possible that delivery limit of event is exceeded while the events are not even published!

Answer (score 1):

The error = 403: Organization total events daily limit exceeded occurs when the maximum number of delivered event notifications within a 24-hour period to all CometD clients has been exceeded.

Note that this error applies to any type of event, including PushTopic, generic, platform, and Change Data Capture events.

See [Streaming API Error Codes](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_streaming.meta/api_streaming/streaming_error_codes.htm)
to learn more

I recommend checking the limits via GET /services/data/v45.0/limits/ and also raise a support case and provide them your org ID to get a detailed usage and the underlying cause of why you are running into this issue